# How can I handle big data best when having a Scala mathematical simulation with data visualization in R?

Tags: r, database, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a mathematical simulation written in scala (random numbers, small calculations, lots of going through collections and producing a lot of data). Currently I produce some csv files as output. Then I load them into R and plot the information. But csv is probably not the best option for sharing big data. My problem is that I don't know how to improve my current approach.

Shall I use a database? Which one? MariaDB?

Shall I calculate the data that shall be plotted in scala while my simulation is running? Without calculating plotting data my program needs 20s for 500000 simulation steps. With calculations it needs more than 3min. But I could use Threads for the calculations. Or shall I give R the pure data and do the calculations on this data in R?

Shall I use Hadoop and Spark? Together with a database?

I am quite confused and hope you have some best practices for me.

Comment: Hi @Temerita, Even if I believe this is a great question to be discussed, it may not be appropriated for **StackOverflow** for being _"too board"_ and _"Mainly opinion based"_. - I would suggest you to search for articles about it and made little Proof Of Concepts of what you find.

Comment: You should also only adress one question.

Comment: I agree! Great q's @Temerita. There's a Data Science SE https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ that's similar to here but doesn't have the code+data narrow focus we have here. I'd suggest posting over there (your login works there too) and give it a go!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You're right it is mainly opinion based but I don't search for the overall best solution but only for one. For me it is enough when one person thinks solution x is the best one. I just need a decision not made by me. I have too less experience for making any decision on this topic by myself.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks for the advice, I'll give it a try :) .

Comment: @hrbrmstr Already migrated to datascience.stackexchange: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41464/what-is-one-good-way-to-handle-big-data-when-having-a-scala-mathematical-simulat